# Quote an inproceedings title in unsrtnat

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, natbib

I am using unsrtnat.bst, but I need entries of type inproceedings to have their title quoted. The title line is:

```
format.title "title" output.check
```

I found a 'quote' function in another .bst file

```
FUNCTION {quote}
{ duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$ "" }
    { "``" swap$ * "''" * }
  if$
}
```

and changed the line to

```
format.title quote "title" output.check
```

and it almost works... it produces:

```
Author "Title", Conference
```

but unfortunately it needs to be

```
Author "Title," Conference
```

(the comma inside the quotes). Can anyone suggest a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The comma after the title is produced by `output.check`.  So a possibility (untested) would be to change the `quote` function in

```
FUNCTION {quoteleft}
{ duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$ "" }
    { "``" swap$ * }
  if$
}
```

and then

```
format.title quoteleft "title" output.check 
title $empty
  {}
  {"''" write$}
  if$
```

Comment: Hm, the left quote appears in the correct position, but there is no right quote at all?

Comment: @DavidDoria forgot `write$` :-)

Comment: Unfortunately, still nothing :(

Comment: The file I am using is here: http://pastebin.com/Zx04E7Mx (line 921 starts the @inproceedings function)

Comment: On IRC, someone showed me to define: FUNCTION {init.seq} { #0 'seq.num := "\def\swaptwo#1#2{#2#1}" write$ } and then replace { "``" swap$ * } in my original 'quote' function with { "``" swap$ * "\swaptwo{''}" * } . It seems to do the trick.

Comment: @Guido if I use your version, the closing quotes end up right before the opening quotes. How can I fix this?